# Is it possible to validate sql and pl/sql syntax on compile time?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I've just killed our CI because I've commit incorrect SLQ file. However I checked it with SQL Developer, but forgot to copy/paste to IDE. The mistake was only in one symbol. elseif -elsif. And build has completed successfully, and it failed only during AT.

But is it a tool for perform sql syntax checks during build? to match sql*plus requirements (for ex: it also can failed due to odd lines).

Comment: As far as I can tell, invalid syntax prevents code to be compiled. Therefore, I'm afraid I don't understand what you actually did and which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Such stuff as `execute immediate 'select + fORm..'` etc. will you see first while execution the program. All JDBC is based on this concept so you parse the SQL first while execution.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Your build process probably didn't notice the problem because PL/SQL compilation issues raise *warnings*, not *exceptions*. Instead of checking each object individually, you're probably better off writing a simple script at the end of the build to verify all objects are valid. (Because of cyclic dependency issues, occasionally a PL/SQL object must be created as temporarily invalid and validated later.)

What is considered a "failure" depends on your precise tools. But in most cases, the below PL/SQL block will raise an exception that will be recognized as a failure:

```
SQL>--Raise an exception if there are any invalid objects.
SQL>declare
  2      v_count number;
  3  begin
  4      select count(*)
  5      into v_count
  6      from all_objects
  7      where owner in ('JHELLER', 'OTHER_SCHEMAS_YOU_CARE_ABOUT')
  8          and status <> 'VALID';
  9
 10      if v_count >= 1 then
 11          raise_application_error(-20000, 'There are '||v_count||' invalid Oracle objects.'||
 12              ' Check your installation log, DBA_ERRORS, etc.');
 13      end if;
 14  end;
 15  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: There are 10 invalid Oracle objects. Check your installation log,
DBA_ERRORS, etc.
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

If that still doesn't count as a failure, you may need to tell SQL*Plus to exit and return a failure error message by adding this at the top of your script:

```
SQL>whenever sqlerror exit failure
```

If even that doesn't work, you'll need to post more details about your setup.